# using enum as string inside an extension swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I declare an enum for my all of the my font-family inside my app. now I want to used as string inside a function for `UIFFont` but it's caused an error!

```
enum Family: String {
    case SansLight = "SansMobile-Light"
    case SansReqular = "SansMobile"
    case SansMedium = "SansMobile-Medium"
}

extension UIFont {
    class func systemFontOfSize(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: Family.RawValue, size: size)
    }
}
```

Error I got:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Family.RawValue.Type' (aka 'String.Type') to expected argument type 'String'
```

How can I use an enum inside UIFont like above with single function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to access the `case` that you have added with your `enum` `Family`.

**It should be**

```
Family.SansLight.rawValue // OR Family.SansReqular.rawValue OR Family.SansMedium.rawValue

//So it goes like 
return UIFont(name: Family.SansLight.rawValue, size: size)
```

**Not directly**

```
Family.RawValue
```

**Note:** `init(name:size:)` will return optional `UIFont?` instance so you need to unwrapped it because in your function you have specify return type to the `UIFont` not `UIFont?`.

Comment: Thanks Nirav. but how can I loop throw all of them in one function? for your suggestion I should write 3 `func`. how I can handled in one single `func`?

Comment: @Sajad Don't get your above comment but if you want all these 3 font in single `UIFont` in instance is not possible, you need to create 3 separate UIFont instance for that. Also check my edited answer note.

Answer (score 2):

you have to write

```
   enum Family: String {
        case SansLight = "SansMobile-Light"
        case SansReqular = "SansMobile"
        case SansMedium = "SansMobile-Medium"
    }

    extension UIFont {
        class func systemFontOfSize(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
            return UIFont(name: Family.SansLight.rawValue, size: size)
        }
    }
```